# Flutter drag down to pop ModalRoute page

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Hei i have app like this

[image]

my question is how can this modal route draggable down to pop route?
this popup page i create from this sample https://stackoverflow.com/a/51908876/10068765

i tried with backdrop on flutter example but its not work, can anyone help with a sample gesturedetector to pop this modal route ?
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think, there other solution also for same,

You can use `showModelBottomSheet` as below

```
showModalBottomSheet(
     context: context,
     builder: (BuildContext bc) {
     return Container();
});
```

Design `Container` base on your requirement may you got a solution.

Answer (score 3):

This uses `onVerticalDragStart` and `onVerticalDragUpdate` to determine if a pointer moves `positionDelta` amount in `timeDelta` time. To trigger it you just have to swipe down fast enough.

```
int initialDragTimeStamp;
int currentDragTimeStamp;
int timeDelta;
double initialPositionY;
double currentPositionY;
double positionYDelta;

void _startVerticalDrag(details) {
  // Timestamp of when drag begins
  initialDragTimeStamp = details.sourceTimeStamp.inMilliseconds;

  // Screen position of pointer when drag begins
  initialPositionY = details.globalPosition.dy;
}

void _whileVerticalDrag(details) {
  // Gets current timestamp and position of the drag event
  currentDragTimeStamp = details.sourceTimeStamp.inMilliseconds;
  currentPositionY = details.globalPosition.dy;

  // How much time has passed since drag began
  timeDelta = currentDragTimeStamp - initialDragTimeStamp;

  // Distance pointer has travelled since drag began
  positionYDelta = currentPositionY - initialPositionY;

  // If pointer has moved more than 50pt in less than 50ms... 
  if (timeDelta < 50 && positionYDelta > 50) {
    // close modal
  }
}
```

And on your GestureDetector:

```
GestureDetector(
  onVerticalDragStart: (details) => _startVerticalDrag(details),
  onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) => _whileVerticalDrag(details)
)
```

`details` refers to [DragUpdateDetails](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/DragUpdateDetails-class.html) and passes event information

Keep in mind if the modal includes a ListView or anything else that would block scroll gestures, you'll want to include [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52910582/6067338) to keep receiving them.